# Custom Implement Action Items using Jetpack

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have been using [onebone Library](https://github.com/onebone/compose-collapsing-toolbar) for implementing collapse toolbar. I wanted to know how to implement action menu like below in the library code:

[image: Top menu buttons at the right top]

I wanted to add 3 menu icons and for that I tried to add code in `CollapsingToolbarScaffold` but its not coming properly on the extreme right corner.

I could find the code ie :

```
@Composable
internal fun MainScreen() {
    val state = rememberCollapsingToolbarScaffoldState()

    CollapsingToolbarScaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        state = state,
        scrollStrategy = ScrollStrategy.ExitUntilCollapsed,
        toolbar = {
            val textSize = (18 + (30 - 18) * state.toolbarState.progress).sp

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(150.dp)
                    .pin()
            )

            Text(
                text = "Guided Selling",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .road(Alignment.CenterStart, Alignment.BottomStart)
                    .padding(60.dp, 16.dp, 16.dp, 16.dp),
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = textSize
            )

            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .pin()
                    .padding(16.dp),

                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.abc_vector_test),
                contentDescription = null
            )

        }
    ) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            items(100) {
                Text(
                    text = "Item $it",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                )
            }
        }

//      Box(
//          modifier = Modifier
//              .fillMaxWidth()
//              .alpha(0.5f)
//              .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)
//              .height(40.dp)
//      )
    }

    CollapsingToolbarScaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        state = rememberCollapsingToolbarScaffoldState(),
        scrollStrategy = ScrollStrategy.ExitUntilCollapsed,
        toolbar = {
            // toolbar contents...

                


        }
    ) {
        // body contents...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution to this custom view; Below is my code for action items.

```
CollapsingToolbarScaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        state = rememberCollapsingToolbarScaffoldState(),
        scrollStrategy = ScrollStrategy.ExitUntilCollapsed,
        toolbar = {
            // toolbar contents...

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(all = 8.dp)
                    .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End

            )
            {

                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_menu_search), contentDescription =null )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_create), contentDescription =null )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_avatar),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(32.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape),
                    contentDescription =null
                )

            }


        }
    )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).